# ubiquityIdentityToken returns value when signed in into iCloud but still returns value after signing out of iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I am trying to check if a user is signed in into iCloud or not on Xode simulator.

```
id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
if (token) {
    _iCloudValue.text = @"Signed In";
} else {
    _iCloudValue.text = @"Not Signed In";
}
```

When I open simulator and signed in into iCloud and then test it returns a value. Similarly when I open simulator and signed out of iCloud it returns null.

However, once I check the signed in scenario, then if I sign out of iCloud and check again, it still returns a value. How do I refresh that token value and check the current status?

The code written above is executed on a button click. So once I have signed out, on clicking the button the code executes again but still returns a value.

Comment: Are you listening for the `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` notification to determine whether you should check again?

Comment: No, could you tell how should I listen to that? And how do I check again?

The code written above is executed on a button click. So once I have signed out, on clicking the button the code executes again but still returns a value